# You can't distinguish accepted and not accepted answers on Meta Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, search, accepted-answer

Search for answers: `is:answer`. Now distinguish accepted and not accepted answers.

[image]

There is no difference. !?!. Should be. As, for example, on Apple.SE,

[image]

or beta sites

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jin has just pushed a fix for this, accepted answers should be distinguishable again soon.

Comment: Wait, *again soon*? Does it mean that it will break again, the second time?

Comment: @nicael No, it means that the fix will appear on the site soon.

Comment: "starting in next build" might be more accurate. Nice fix!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the grammar in this answer (well, aside from the comma abuse -.-).